# Drupal: URL redirects in .htaccess for multiple sites and a single codebase

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I'm using Drupal 8. Multiple sites sharing a single codebase. One .htaccess file for all.

I am receiving the same "page not found error" across all sites.  Hackers attempting to break in to the site, presumably.

For example, someone tries to visit `https:domain1/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` and `https:domain2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`   ...  Different domain names, but always the same addresses.

Other addresses include `/phpmyadmin/scripts/setup.php` and `/1/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml` and so on.

Using .htaccess, what is the most efficient means of redirecting all of these to an internal or external site so that my pages are not even served?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, the way Drupal and the web server work is that when request arrives, if it matches “serverName” and document root and they points to Drupal then the web-server will hand that to Drupal to handle. 
So,  you have to ask if this is Drupal destined and if so, handle the redirect at Drupal (probably using the redirect module )

If you want set it up at at web-server level and you have access or using .htaccess then like :

```
RedirectMatch ^/wp-admin/(.*)$ http://example.com/404/$1
```

Note, there are plenty of other ways to write the above , but it’s simplest and lightest

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very common issue about CMS vulnerabilities and hosting security. And security issues is something that can not be done by a simple static action because there's always a new vulnerability. So be careful to always run :

```
composer update
```

To have always the last bug fixes and securities updates. Specially when you use modules like webform. At the moment Drupal offers more than one module for better securing your app. And in your case you need to identify IP addresses used by hacking robots and blocking them by using [Perimeter](https://www.drupal.org/project/perimeter) .
The good news that the community arround Drupal is very concerned about security. For further reading and securing Drupal you can uses those modules but the more modules you install the more you have performance issues:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/clamav
- https://www.drupal.org/project/file_upload_secure_validator
- https://www.drupal.org/project/key
- https://www.drupal.org/project/csp
- https://www.drupal.org/project/noopener_filter
- https://www.drupal.org/project/hsts
- https://www.drupal.org/project/securelogin
  ...

I also recommend the use of fast [404/403 Drupal error pages](https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005246714-Using-Fast-404-to-improve-Drupal-performance) to not allow using of Database or more code running to serve that kind of pages.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.